# getting twitter userpics without hitting limits on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

My iOS app is a small social network that supports login with twitter. As part of functionality I need to access twitter userpics, to e.g. show them in user profile or next to a notification/post.

Since twitter API 1.0 has been deprecated recently, I need to use v1.1. 
On API 1.0 getting userpic was dead simple - one API call that returns an URL for the image. 

Now every time I need twitter userpic I follow the route of authenticating with APP key and secret, getting large JSON with user info and picking profile image URL from there.

The problem is that I hit API call limits. It did not happen on v1.0. What do you think would be  the best solution to tackle that? I can think of some:

- use disk cache (caches image on each iOS device). On the current implementation I cache image with image URL being the key; this could be reworked to cache image with user name being the key as it would not count against twitter API limits
- cache link to userpic on the backend (we use parse.com)
- cache image itself on the backend
- somehow optimize logic of asking twitter for profile URL <- this is the preferred since it does not require major code reworks.

Q1: What is the best solution on your opinion? 

Q2: Can you see any way to query twitter on link to user pic without hitting the quota ?

Thanks, 
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was resolved in a following way:

1. Local (on-devise) caching with SDImageCache, a part of SDWebImage lib.
2. Caching of link to twitter userpic in a parse.com DB (our backend).
3. If the link to user pic is not available, twitter rest API is being requested for that link

The second step is added to handle case e.g. a new user logged in with twitter and we are to get his user pic from twitter; that user posts something to the feed, and when bunch of guys open his post we don't want twitter to reject requests due to quota limit; upon the the first request to twitter API the link is stored in the DB.

Hope it helps somebody.

Cheers,
Dan.